# MongoDB - Update / Replace array field with subdocument to embed its content

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

## Description

After reworking my data construct, I want to embed a document (or parts of it) from a different collection. Pay your attention to event.tags[]. Currently, there are only their stringified _ids (as plain string, no ObjectId!) stored, but I want to migrate their content, like `{tags.name, tags._id}`. I want to update/replace the original `event.tags` with the content of `tag`-documents.

## Data

**Collection "events"**

```
db.events.insertMany([{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6c5b0594911c0b7231643d"),
    "title" : "Test Event",
    "tags" : [ 
        "5fd8cef2368c625a9d7516cb"
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb3896afc13ae2ed1000000"),
    "title" : "Test Event 2",
    "tags" : [ 
        "5fd8cef2368c625a9d7516cb", 
        "5fd8cfb04a4a6063ab4ca4bf", 
        "5fd8cfb04a4a6063ab4ca4c0"
    ]
}
]);
```

**Collection "tags"**

```
db.tags.insertMany([{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cef2368c625a9d7516cb"),
    "name" : "Foo",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-15T14:57:54.096Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cfb04a4a6063ab4ca4bf"),
    "name" : "Bar",
    "createdBy" : "embo@team-con.de",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-16T14:57:54.096Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cfb04a4a6063ab4ca4c0"),
    "name" : "Foobar",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-17T14:57:54.096Z")
}
]);
```

## Expected result

I want to achieve to embed some/all fields of collection *"tags"* matched by *"events.tags"* <-> *"tags._id"* as an array of embedded/nested documents. This will be part of a migration script, running over mongoDB API >4.0 thru node.js.

Goal: I want to replace an Array of Strings (see collection events) with certain information of a DIFFERENT collection (see collection tags) and save it back to collection events (migrate process). So I assume, I have to fetch/lookup something from `tag` collection and need a mechanism to replace the string (events.tags[x]) with complex objects ({tags._id, tags.name})

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6c5b0594911c0b7231643d"),
    "title" : "Test Event",
    "tags" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cef2368c625a9d7516cb"),
        "name" : "Foo",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-12-15T14:57:54.096Z")
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb3896afc13ae2ed1000000"),
    "title" : "Test Event 2",
    "tags" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cef2368c625a9d7516cb"),
        "name" : "Foo"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cfb04a4a6063ab4ca4bf"),
        "name" : "Bar"
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd8cfb04a4a6063ab4ca4c0"),
        "name" : "Foobar"
    }]
}
```

*Baby steps*

I tried to use the aggregation pipeline and started by matching and lookup their content to [replaceWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) in the last step. I am not too familiar to solve this via the aggregation pipeline.

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
    { $match: { tags: { "$exists" : true } } },
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: "tags",
           localField: "tags",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "taags"
         }
    },
    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert tag's id from string to objectId using `$toObjectId` operator, before `$lookup` stage,

- `$addFields` to add new fields and update/format existing fields
- `$map` to iterate loop of `tags` array
- `$toObjectId` to convert string objectId to objectId type
- put the name `tags` in `as` property of `$lookup` stage

```
  // $match stage here
  {
    $addFields: {
      tags: {
        $map: {
          input: "$tags",
          in: { $toObjectId: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      localField: "tags",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "tags"
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dGY9QwI-HfB)

- With the aggregation query you can not update current events collection, but you can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage to result in new collection, supported from MongoDB 4.4,
- put this stage at last stage

```
  { $out: "updated_events" }
```

---

The second option is to prepare a script to do the manual process,

1. Find all records from the events collection
2. loop the results of events collection
3. inside loop execute find query by passing tags ids in tags collection
4. inside loop update events collection by replacing result from 3) step

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Are there any insights about the replaceAll pipeline usage?

Comment: the definition in docs *"Replaces all instances of a search string in an input string with a replacement string."* is enough to understand `$replaceAll` operator.

Comment: I appreciate your effort and guidance. Nevertheless, I struggle with the aspect to replace an array of IDs with complex, nested objects - no plain string replacements like renaming in lower/upper cases. I replaced `$replaceAll` with `$replaceWith` because I linked the wrong one. So I am still in doubt if this will suit my needs. Do you agree?

Comment: I am not getting your question, why you want to use `$replaceWith`?

Comment: I am open to edit my unclear question. Goal: I want to replace an Array of Strings (see collection events) with certain information of a *DIFFERENT* collection (see collection tags). So I assume, I have to fetch/lookup something from that collection and need a mechanism to replace the string (`events.tags[x]`) with complex objects (`{tags._id, tags.name}`). Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Can you confirm updated answer and playground link.

Comment: do you want to update the documents permanently in collection? if yes then aggregation only format the result means it will fetch documents only can't update in collection.

Comment: Yes Sir, I need to replace the original document `event` in its collection. That's part of the migration process to a new schema version. After that, i will delete collection 'tags' because everything is in collection 'events'. That's my original question. Sorry if i was misleading/unclear.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can use $out operator if you want to use aggregation query, it will result in new collection, you can remove the old collection `events` and after that rename the new collection to `events`., but make sure this $out operator will support from mongodb 4.4.

Comment: In your answer, you say "with the aggregation query you can update current events collection". That would be awesome because I do not need to rename collections. Any hints to same collection replacements? I will be fully satisfied with your feedback and help. Great job.

Comment: was a mistake, you can not update any collection by aggregation, but you can use $out stage to result in new collection,  after that you can remove old collection and rename the new collection to events